# The recursive function in python stops at step 2500 even if the limit is 100000

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
start_time=time.time()
im=Image.open("Capturecasa.png")
data=np.asarray(im,dtype=np.uint8)
back=np.zeros(4,dtype=np.uint8)
back=data[1000][200]
def recursiv(i,j,k):
    global data
    data[i][j]=[3,3,3,255]
    if abs(data[i+1,j,0]-back[0])<5 or abs(data[i+1,j,1]-back[1])<5 or abs(data[i+1,j,2]-back[2])<5:
        print(k)
        return recursiv(i+1,j,k+1)
    if abs(data[i-1,j,0]-back[0])<5 or abs(data[i-1,j,1]-back[1])<5 or abs(data[i-1,j,2]-back[2])<5:
        print(k)
        return recursiv(i-1,j,k+1)
    if abs(data[i,j+1,0]-back[0])<5 or abs(data[i,j+1,1]-back[1])<5 or abs(data[i,j+1,2]-back[2])<5:
        print(k)
        return recursiv(i,j+1,k+1)
    if abs(data[i,j-1,0]-back[0])<5 or abs(data[i,j-1,1]-back[1])<5 or abs(data[i,j-1,2]-back[2])<5:
        print(k)
        return recursiv(i,j-1,k+1)
recursiv(100,200,1)
print(1)
im=Image.fromarray(data,'RGBA')
im.show()
print("--- %s seconds ---"%(time.time()-start_time))
```

This program replaces the background of the image with another color. The program stops at step 2500 regardless of the image. The code does not return any errors other than

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
  if abs(data[i+1,j,0]-back[0])<5 or abs(data[i+1,j,1]-back[1])<5 or abs(data[i+1,j,2]-back[2])<5:
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any advantage to implementing this function recursively?

Comment: The error seems to be unrelated to recursion.

Comment: Yes, because I want to delimit some buttons

Comment: If it were a problem with recursion depth, you would get an error message about recursion depth. Your message is about overflow, probably integer overflow. These are `numpy` integers, not Python integers. When 8-byte integers overflow, they typically go negative. When unsigned integers overflow, they just truncate. That will confuse any algorithm. And because the message is a warning, not an error, that indicates that your computation is proceeding with duff data.

Answer (score 0):

- There doesn't appear to be any advantage to implementing this function recursively?
- If you find yourself changing the recursion limit (or another similar system limit), it's good to stop and ask yourself whether you may be approaching the whole problem in an unfortunate way. Sometimes changing the system limit is necessary; often, a completely different solution may be much more straightforward.

In this case, the `recursiv` function can be re-written iteratively, like this:

```
def iterativ(i, j, k):
    global data
    while True:
        data[i][j] = [3, 3, 3, 255]
        if (
            abs(data[i + 1, j, 0] - back[0]) < 5
            or abs(data[i + 1, j, 1] - back[1]) < 5
            or abs(data[i + 1, j, 2] - back[2]) < 5
        ):
            print(k)
            i, j, k = i + 1, j, k + 1
        elif (
            abs(data[i - 1, j, 0] - back[0]) < 5
            or abs(data[i - 1, j, 1] - back[1]) < 5
            or abs(data[i - 1, j, 2] - back[2]) < 5
        ):
            print(k)
            i, j, k = i - 1, j, k + 1
        elif (
            abs(data[i, j + 1, 0] - back[0]) < 5
            or abs(data[i, j + 1, 1] - back[1]) < 5
            or abs(data[i, j + 1, 2] - back[2]) < 5
        ):
            print(k)
            i, j, k = i, j + 1, k + 1
        elif (
            abs(data[i, j - 1, 0] - back[0]) < 5
            or abs(data[i, j - 1, 1] - back[1]) < 5
            or abs(data[i, j - 1, 2] - back[2]) < 5
        ):
            print(k)
            i, j, k = i, j - 1, k + 1
        else:
            break
```

Notes:

- If you're after a flood-fill spreading in all directions (rather than one direction at a time), use a queue:

  ```
   import collections
   def queue(i, j, k):
       global data
       q = collections.deque((i, j, k))
       while q:
           i, j, k = q.popleft()
           data[i][j] = [3, 3, 3, 255]
           if (
               abs(data[i + 1, j, 0] - back[0]) < 5
               or abs(data[i + 1, j, 1] - back[1]) < 5
               or abs(data[i + 1, j, 2] - back[2]) < 5
           ):
               print(k)
               q.append((i + 1, j, k + 1))
           if (
               abs(data[i - 1, j, 0] - back[0]) < 5
               or abs(data[i - 1, j, 1] - back[1]) < 5
               or abs(data[i - 1, j, 2] - back[2]) < 5
           ):
               print(k)
               q.append((i - 1, j, k + 1))
           if (
               abs(data[i, j + 1, 0] - back[0]) < 5
               or abs(data[i, j + 1, 1] - back[1]) < 5
               or abs(data[i, j + 1, 2] - back[2]) < 5
           ):
               print(k)
               q.append((i, j + 1, k + 1))
           if (
               abs(data[i, j - 1, 0] - back[0]) < 5
               or abs(data[i, j - 1, 1] - back[1]) < 5
               or abs(data[i, j - 1, 2] - back[2]) < 5
           ):
               print(k)
               q.append((i, j - 1, k + 1))
  ```
- If you want to replace the pixels globally throughout the image, use matrix operations.